# Where does gcc go to link a library?

Tags: c, gcc

I have simple c program called jpeg.c and my Makefile was like this:

```
all:
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall jpeg.c -o jpeg
clean:
    $(RM) jpeg
```

My code did not compile until I added "-ljpeg"

```
all:
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall jpeg.c -o jpeg -ljpeg
clean:
    $(RM) jpeg
```

I'm just wondering where exactly does gcc go to look for the jpeg library as specified by the -l option?

Comment: Without subtlety: `strace -f -o mylog gcc -std=c99 ...` then `grep libjpeg mylog`. More specific, pass gcc the option `-Wl,--verbose`, which tells the linker to be verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-print-search-dirs` option should give you the answer.

Comment: Is there any way that I can tell where gcc finds the jpeg library in particular?

Comment: Sure `gcc -Lsome_path`

Comment: I apologize for my poorly phrased question. Actually I wanted to ask if there is a way that I can ask gcc to show me where it finds the jpeg library. "tell" as in "know". Sorry about that

Comment: if you compile in verbose mode then you should see what the compiler really does. `gcc -v -o foo foo.c`

Answer (score 1):

By default `gcc` is following the *builtin configuration* which in `gcc` terms is the `spec` file, you can see the spec file that is relative to a particular `gcc` executable with

```
gcc -dumpspecs
```

docs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) .